# How does Firefox(or dld manager) determine the size of a file being downloaded?

Tags: firefox, filesize

Actually what I want to do is to FOOL the browser by saying that the file to be downloaded is 1KB, no matter what the file size is but it should download the entire file!

Comment: This is unlikely to work well. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Content-length: 1024` in the headers, but some browsers make take that as gospel and cut off the transfer after that kilobyte's transferred. You have no control over what the client does with a download. At most you can give some hints (content type, length, disposition) and after that it's out of your hands.

Comment: @Marc thanks for reply. The main problem is that they have put up a filesize(30MB) limit at our college, for all those who connect through WiFi in the college Campus. Now it isn't that i need to download BIG files every now and then but last week when i had to download VirtualBox(40Mb approx) i was stuck! is there any solution to this problem???

Comment: How's the limit being applied? If it's a firewall thing and it's keeping a count of bytes transferred, then you're stuck - you can't stick a header somewhere and tell the firewall "hey, this is really only 1 byte, please ignore the 50 bajillion terabytes I'll really be transferring".

Comment: @Marc all i know is the Firewall used is 'Fortiguard' but the Download limit is set recently. Whenever i try to download a file greater than 35MB i get redirected to a page displaying an error message saying that 'file size exceeding the download limit' (this is not the exact message as i am at home right now, but then the "text" of the error message doesn't matter i guess!).

Comment: Well, unless you've got an external proxy somewhere, you can't control what the sending site will put in for its headers. If that redirect was immediate, then the firewall would have to be inspecting the headers and looking for Content-length - otherwise it would have to actually download the requested file and see how long it really is, which would take time. Set up a script on your home server that sets a 1k length in the headers, but tries to send 50, and then try downloading it at school. see wha thappens.

Comment: I have also observed that in some cases the 'filesize' doesn't appear until the download is complete, I can't recall an example at the moment but it does happen. Not sure whether it is useful in my case ?!?

Comment: Some sites don't set a content length header and just start spitting out bytes - the browser will just download until the sending site closes the connection. It's normal in some cases, especially when you're dynamically building a large file and stream it out as it's built - you can't tell how big it'll be in advance.

Comment: @Marc: thanks for such prompt replies. I do own a website, will it do? or i will have to keep a server running at my place? can you point out some tut for same?? Thanks once again... :)

Comment: There's lots of PHP proxies out there, just google for them. But whatever you end up with, you'd still need to mod it to forge the content-length header.